# when choosing c++(GDB/LLDB) on vscode I receive cannot read property 'includes' of undefined error

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina, vscode-debugger

(Intro) (Question is after intro)
First time on stack overflow, and getting into coding for the first time. Would appreciate any help.

The purpose of why I'm trying to get into c++ programming is to have a base level foundation of how to create and develop programs (ie games, apps, etc.) Any forums, websites, and communities to join would be much appreciated. I am learning this to get into blockchain, probably solidity on the Ethereum network.

MACOS: Catalina 10.15

**C++**:
https://cppinstitute.org/cpa-c-certified-associate-programmer-certification

IDE/Compiler ***Visual Studio Code***:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

---

On the compiler I'm trying to set it up so that I can download the codes on cppinstitute and compile the program on VScode. I am following the steps on *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp* and here are the steps taken:

1. Built Helloworld files and tasks.json in the .vscode folder using
   "c/c++:clang++ build active file"
2. I ran the build and typed: `ls -a -1`
   terminal reads:

```
.
..
.vscode
helloworld
helloworld.cpp
helloworld.dSYM
```

3. I am able to run: "./helloworld"
   terminal reads:
   Hello C++ World from VS Code and the C++ extension!"

**Problem** 4."Debug helloworld.cpp"
I am able to choose "Run > Add Configuration"
and then when I select "C++ (GDB/LLB)" I get a "cannot read property 'includes' of undefined error" on the bottom right.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: `gdb` is very pedantic if its `bin` directory is not on your `PATH`, start VSC from the correct shell/terminal, check `$PATH`

Comment: Seems like a null bug in VS code/C++ extension for automatically creating the file. You can create the `launch.json` file manually in the same folder as the `tasks.json` file. To get a default file, see the debugging section of the intro docs for [C++ with Clang on Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_debug-helloworldcpp)